# How to get a file's UTI from the command line in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line

Is there a command line utility to which I can pass a filename, that will return applicable UTIs for that file?

For example:

```
hypothetical-uti-fetcher /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Aqua\ Blue.jpg
```

might give me:

```
public.jpeg
public.image
public.data
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `mdls` command to find the UTI for a file:

`mdls /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Aqua\ Blue.jpg`

and it will give you a bunch of info, toward the top it will say something like

```
kMDItemContentType             = "public.plain-text"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  `mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Aqua\ Blue.jpg` is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad this helped.

Comment: Suppose I turned off my Spotlight index and I seem to have no metadata stored. (mdls whatever-file just says that the file was not found). How do the md* services generate the content types in the first place?

Comment: Even more concise, would be `mdls -name kMDItemContentType <filename> | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Even more concise, would be mdls -name kMDItemContentType <filename>

Answer (score 8):

The mdls command only seems to work on Spotlight indexed files. If you run it on a mounted disk image, cd or thumb drive it may return no information at all.

When you're developing a Quicklook Plugin it's also useful to use the following command to see what UTIs Quicklook thinks a file has and which plugins it uses for the preview:

```
qlmanage -d 4 -p /path/to/file
```

Comment: The cited site is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Even if Spotlight hasn't indexed the file you can still use mdls to find the UTI using:

`mdls -name kMDItemContentType /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

You get create a workflow for getting the UTI from selected file.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        set ff to item 1 of input
        set uti to type identifier of ff
        set ans to display dialog uti buttons {"Copy to Clipboard", "OK"} default button "Copy to Clipboard"
        if button returned of ans is "Copy to Clipboard" then
            set the clipboard to uti
        end if
    end tell
end run
```